# leadbolt ads causes many asynctasks - refresh rate for ads?

Tags: android, leadbolt

Using leadbolt ads it causes my app in the device to run many asynctasks and it crashes:

```
Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
05-22 20:16:08.005: W/System.err(13637): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/logcat_0.txt (Permission denied)
05-22 20:16:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13637): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-22 20:16:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13637): java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: pool=128/128, queue=10/10
05-22 20:16:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13637):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1961)
05-22 20:16:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13637):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:794)
05-22 20:16:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13637):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1315)
05-22 20:16:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13637):    at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:394)
05-22 20:16:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13637):    at com.hqiachcfpy.AdController.loadIcon(Unknown Source)
05-22 20:16:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13637):    at com.hqiachcfpy.s.onAdOptin(Unknown Source)
05-22 20:16:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13637):    at com.hqiachcfpy.AdOptinRequest.onPostExecute(Unknown Source)
05-22 20:16:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13637):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
05-22 20:16:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13637):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
05-22 20:16:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13637):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
05-22 20:16:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13637):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-22 20:16:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13637):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-22 20:16:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13637):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
05-22 20:16:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13637):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-22 20:16:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13637):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-22 20:16:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13637):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:895)
05-22 20:16:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13637):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:653)
05-22 20:16:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(13637):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-22 20:16:08.045: W/System.err(13637): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/plog.log (Permission denied)
```

Also , it gives me all the time:

```
GC_CONCURRENT freed 402K, 48% free 3271K/6279K, external 657K/1169K, paused 4ms+6ms
```

The code I am using is:

```
 //Leadbolt code
        myController = new AdController(this, "111111");
        myController.loadStartAd("22222222", "222222");

public void onDestroy()
    {
        myController.destroyAd();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

Why am I having this problem?

Also, is there any need to define any refresh rate for the ads?

For example for the Notification ads you can define them from leadboltnetwork.

For App Add?Or App Icon?

--------------------UPDATE-------------------------------

I noticed that if I activate internet connection , then the app doesn't give all the above!And doesn't crash!It works fine!

Comment: not sure what you are doing. asynctask don't run parallely. They run on a single thread. if you are looking for parallel execution use a executor. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html. See the order of execution in the link

Comment: @Raghunandan:I am not doing anything..The ads create these asynctask's.I don't use any asynctask for the ads.

Comment: it's a file not found exception and the logcat states permission denied clearly

Comment: @Raghunandan:Yes ,but when I remove the ads code I am not taking the problem

Comment: i guess your app is trying to access files in /data. the device is rejecting permission for the same. Try rooting your device. But i would not advice you to do that.

Comment: @Raghunandan:My app uses database.But I just want to put ads in my app.What should I do?Thanks!

Comment: @George things are two: or the leadbolt leaks or you are using it in the wrong way. We need a bit more of context (code)

Comment: @blackbelt:I am in contact with leadbolt and I am waiting for a response.In the meantime I used another sdk and now the app doesn't crash but it still gives me the garbage.Is this "ok"?I mean, I want to release my app.Is there a problem if I do it now? (because it gives garbage)?I just wanted your opinion.Thanks!

Comment: Messages from Garbage collector are normal

Comment: @blackbelt:Ok, so it is no problem?Because else I read that this is a memory leak and else that is normal.Anyway ,if you want make an answer (because you said it was a leak from leadbolt).Thank you!

Comment: @George Messages from the garbage collector are normal. If you want check for potential memory leak you have to download the MAT tool for eclipse

Comment: @blackbelt:If you want make an answer as I said above in order to accept.

Comment: nope there is no need. If you want you can delete the question

Comment: @blackbelt:Ok, I just wanted to be right.(deleting an answer requires to flag it and to be checked by the moderator if I am not mistaking)

Comment: I cant see any answer

Comment: @blackbelt:This is what you said " things are two: or the leadbolt leaks or you are using it in the wrong way." That's why.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30765/discussion-between-blackbelt-and-george)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I used another sdk from leadbolt and the problem solved.

(I still have garbage collection though)